# Why Morgan Logger server middleware doesn't work in separate file?

Tags: express, logging, next.js, middleware, morgan

I am following [this tutorial](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/morgan.html) in my `nextjs` app for adding a new **middleware** for logging so I have the following code in my **server.js**:

```
// create a write stream (in append mode)
const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' })

// setup the logger
server.use(morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream }))
```

And it is working without a problem.

**But** I want to have the logic in a **separate** file in the middleware directory so I have :

**middlewares/logger/index.js**

```
import morgan from "morgan";
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';


export default (req, res, next) => {
  var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), { flags: 'a' })

  return morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream });
};
```

and in my **server.js** I will have: (after importing and initializing stuff)

```
  server.use(logger);
  server.use(othermiddlewareone);
  server.use(othermiddlewaretwo);
```

The other middlewares are working fine but this one breaks. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the **middleware** like this and now it is working fine :)

```
import type { Request, Response, Next } from './types';
import morgan from "morgan";
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'server.log'), { flags: 'a' })
const logger = morgan('combined', { stream: accessLogStream })

export default async (req: Request, res: Response, next: Next) => {
  logger(req, res, function (err) {
    return next();
  })
};
```

Comment: Are you using Next JS framework or Express?

Comment: @Simon Next JS framework with express server!

Comment: Do you manage to log `:remote-user` with the `combined` log?